# C - Modifying a variable's value using a function and using it in another function

Tags: c, pointers, variables

I've been trying to write a Linux driver. First I've written a helper file so that it can determine which of the two drivers should be loaded (only one of them, and not both) using procfs. But it seems `is_asd32` is always 0 and doesn't change to 1 when needed. Here's what I tried for the helper (trimmed so that it shows the relevant code):
*Note that the helper is initialized at `fs_initcall`, and I made sure it executes a script from userspace. The drivers are initialized at `device_initcall`.

I've tried using pointers:

```
static char proc_data[4];
int *is_asd32 = NULL;

static ssize_t drivers_write(struct file *file, const char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *data )
{
    if(count > 4)
       return -EFAULT;
    if(copy_from_user(proc_data, buf, count))
       return -EFAULT;

    if(!strncmp("1",(char*)proc_data,1))
       *is_asd32 = 1;
    //no else block, just leave is_asd32 = 0
}

int use_asd32()
{
    if (*is_asd32)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Also tried:

```
static char proc_data[4];
int *is_asd32 = NULL;
static int one = 1;

static ssize_t drivers_write(struct file *file, const char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *data )
{
    if(count > 4)
       return -EFAULT;
    if(copy_from_user(proc_data, buf, count))
       return -EFAULT;

    if(!strncmp("1",(char*)proc_data,1))
       is_asd32 = &one;
    //no else block, just leave is_asd32 = 0
}

int use_asd32()
{
    if (*is_asd32)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Both crashes the system. I guess a segfault. So maybe something's wrong with my pointer usage.

First attempt (with global variables):

```
static char proc_data[4];
int is_asd32;

static ssize_t drivers_write(struct file *file, const char *buf,size_t count,loff_t *data )
{
    if(count > 4)
       return -EFAULT;
    if(copy_from_user(proc_data, buf, count))
       return -EFAULT;

    if(!strncmp("1",(char*)proc_data,1))
       is_asd32 = 1;
    //no else block, just leave is_asd32 = 0
}

int use_asd32()
{
    if (is_asd32)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

First driver init code:

```
extern int use_asd32(void);`
static int __init first_driver(void)
{
    if (use_asd32())
       return -ENODEV; // let the second driver load successfully
   ......................
}
```

Second driver init code:

```
extern int use_asd32(void);
static int __init second_driver(void);
{
    if (!use_asd32())
        return -ENODEV;
............
}
```

`use_asd32()` return value should change as `is_asd32()` changes

Comment: This: `int *is_asd32 = NULL;` followed by `*is_asd32 = 1;` will probably cause a segfault. Why not just use `int is_asd32 = 0;` for the status, followed by `is_asd32 = 1;` ?

Comment: That's why I also tried         is_asd32 = &one. From my question, I already tried using a global variable         is_asd32 and changing it to 1 in the procfs write function, but it's always zero when         use_asd32() tries to access it

Comment: A global variable is only initialised once. You must be resetting it to `0` somewhere else in the code, or have a bug somwhere that causes it to be overwritten accidentally.

Comment: Sorry, just edited the code. Nope, the `int is_asd32` is present in the helper file. The `drivers_write` function is supposed to modify `is_asd32`. The `use_asd32()` function relies on `is_asd32` variable whether to return `1` or `0`. This `use_asd32()` is then used as an extern function so that both drivers can check whether the other one is should be loaded

Comment: If `is_asd32` is *never* `1` then you should examine the program logic, and your suppositions as to why it should be set to `1`. Trying to use a pointer seems to be an irrelevance. Aside: `int use_asd32()` is over-complicated. It can be simply `return is_asd32;`

Comment: This check `if(!strncmp("1",(char*)proc_data,1))` seems to be correct as I added a tracepoint into it, so `is_asd32` should be set to one whenever I command `echo 1 > /proc/drivers_write`, i'm guessing the change in `is_asd32` is only seen by `drivers_write()`. Other than that, maybe using pointers is better

Comment: Well set a break-on-write to that variable and see what/when it is written to.

Comment: If you are writing `is_ads32` in an execution context which is different from reading it, the optimizer could also shorten the access to a constant as it never sees a write to it in the compilation unit. Access modifier `volatile` is your friend in this case.